# How to create a modal login popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqmodal, modalpopup

I need to add login modal popup in my project like Digg's login popup.

What are different modal box popups to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jqueryui.com/ - their [dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog) is quite flexible :)

as for tips, you can add your login form to the page in it's own div that is hidden via css. Then your login link/button/whatever can open it.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you need **[this one.](http://www.visual-blast.com/javascript/digg-style-signup-form-with-jquery/)**